# Credit card processing on webpage vs using 3rd party gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

I would like to ask about the differences between accepting credit cards using 3rd party gateway (on checkout, customer is redirected to 3rd party webpage, where inserts card details and pays) and processing credit cards directly on page (customer inserts card numbers to online shop form).

Do I understand correctly that the latter is cheaper? I have seen several smaller online shops having such payment implemented. What are the requirements?

We operate online shop with food supplements and apparently this is a high risk category. Payment gateways charge much more for processing this kind of products.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Processing cards directly on your page involves other costs. You need to comply to PCI rules, which is not necessarily 'cheap'. Then you have to send the card & transaction details through some kind of gateway anyway, so the charges will get you regardless.